# Regex to match and get {{aaa}}

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I want to do following:

Convert

"{{  interface_ID }} THERE SHOU{{interface_ID}}LD BE CODE HERE: {{interface_ID}}"

to

"{&#8203;{  interface_ID }} THERE SHOU{&#8203;{interface_ID}}LD BE CODE HERE: {&#8203;{interface_ID}}"

I tried following code but its not getting me correct results

```
    Pattern CURLY_BRACKETS_PLACEHOLDER = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}");
    Matcher m = CURLY_BRACKETS_PLACEHOLDER.matcher(htmlString);
    if(m.find()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
            String script = m.group(i);
            String scriptWithPlaceholder = "{{"+script+"}}";
            String replacementToken = "{"+ ZERO_WIDTH_SPACE_CHARACTER +"{"+script+"}}";
            htmlString = htmlString.replace(scriptWithPlaceholder, replacementToken);
        }
    }
    return htmlString;
```

Please let me know how I can achive this

Comment: can you format input and output strings in question?

Comment: Please provide the current results of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the pattern that you tried, you could match using a capture group for the part after the first curly.

```
\{(\{.*?}})
```

And replace with

```
{&#8203;$1
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XJ9wdP/1) and a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/tdRXau)

Example code

```
String regex = "\\{(\\{.*?\\}\\})";
String string = "{{ interface_ID }} THERE SHOU{{interface_ID}}LD BE CODE HERE: {{interface_ID}}";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

System.out.println(matcher.replaceAll("{&#8203;$1"));
```

Output

```
{&#8203;{ interface_ID }} THERE SHOU{&#8203;{interface_ID}}LD BE CODE HERE: {&#8203;{interface_ID}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern CURLY_BRACKETS_PLACEHOLDER = Pattern.compile("\\{\\{(.*?)\\}\\}");
Matcher m = CURLY_BRACKETS_PLACEHOLDER.matcher(htmlString);
while(m.find()) {
        String script = m.group(1);
        String scriptWithPlaceholder = "{{"+script+"}}";
        String replacementToken = "{"+ ZERO_WIDTH_SPACE_CHARACTER +"{"+script+"}}";
        htmlString = htmlString.replace(scriptWithPlaceholder, replacementToken);
}
return htmlString;
```